# XPATH expression match="TAGNAME" matches but match="PARENT/TAGNAME" does not

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am new to XSLT and want to remove all "Private" tags from References in a csproj-File and then introduce Private="False" tags behind every "HintPath" instead. I wrote a working solution for that without fully understanding what I am doing:

XSLT

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:DUMMY="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"> <!-- use DUMMY namespace as default, would otherwise write missing ns explicitly -->
 <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> <!-- encoding as required for output file, indent=yes: would write all text in one line otherwise -->
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> <!-- delete all white spaces -->

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Private"/> <!-- obsolete line: without the namespace workaround: no match -->
<xsl:template match="DUMMY:Private"/> <!-- working line: only deletes tags itself, not indention -->
<xsl:template match="DUMMY:Reference/Private"/> <!-- obsolete line: Does not match! -->
<xsl:template match="DUMMY:Reference//Private"/> <!-- obsolete line: Does also not match! -->

<xsl:template match="DUMMY:HintPath">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:element name="Private">
    <xsl:text>False</xsl:text>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"> <!-- The original document has an anonymous default namespace -->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Configuration">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>$(SolutionDir)..\..\public\Bin\$(Configuration)\Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Core">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>$(SolutionDir)..\..\public\Bin\$(Configuration)\Core.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Data">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>$(SolutionDir)..\..\public\Bin\$(Configuration)\Data.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

As stated: that works for me, but it was quite complicated to find out so far. Is there a better way to accomplish that task with XSLT?

I dont like the fact that there could be collateral damage if "Private" tags appear somewhere else in the document than in "Reference"s. But I did not find a way to specify it including that parent tag. Any hints?

Second question: Is there a simpler way of handling the namespaces?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the prefix to qualify all elements names: `<xsl:template match="DUMMY:Reference/DUMMY:Private"/>`.